# Ruby - list minus

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have two list

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2]
b = a.uniq # b = [1, 2, 3, 4]

c = a - b
```

the result gets `c = []`

I expects the result `c = [1, 2]`

How can I get this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the expected result according to the [Array documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M000273).

If you want to get the values which have multiple occurrences within the array you could something like:

```
a.uniq.keep_if {|v| a.count(v) > 1}
```

If Ruby 1.8 is used, `keep_if` is not available, so you need to use something like:

```
a.uniq.delete_if {|v| a.count(v) == 1}
```

(Both methods keep `a` intact)

Comment: keep_if is not in ruby 2.0 and above versions

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get elements from array which appears more than once you can use following code:

```
a.delete_if { |x| a.count(x) <= 1 }.uniq
```

If you want to perform sub operation on two arrays based on elements position you can use following code:

```
i = 0
a.drop_while { |x| b[i+=1] == x }.uniq
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M000273)

> Array Difference—Returns a new array that is a copy of the original array, removing any items that also appear in other_ary. (If you need set-like behavior, see the library class Set.)

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for all duplicates or the opposite of uniq? Maybe this link will help: [Identify duplicates in an array](http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/3838)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to find elements that have duplicates. Here are several ways, pick the one you like:

```
a.select { |x| a.count(x) > 1 }.uniq
a.sort.each_cons(2).map { |x,y| x if x == y }.compact
a.group_by{|x|x}.values.select{|k|k.size>1}.map(&:first)
```